# How to make a regression model with customer data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a customer dataset as

- Data X: `4096 x N`
- Label Y: `Nx1`

I want to build a regression model for my data (1 or 2 layers). Which operators should I use to build my model in tensorflow? Thanks

Update: where `N` is number of label. The dataX has N vectors. In which, the vector1 `4096x1` corresponding to label `1`, vector2 `4096x1` corresponding to label `2`, ..., vectorN `4096x1` corresponding to label `N`. So the data X may be `4096xN` and label Y is `Nx1`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a simple `Linear Regression`, you can create weight and bias variable as

```
W = tf.get_variable('W', shape=[4096, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.get_variable('b', shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32)
```

Now, assuming your input to be of shape `[N, 4096]` and output of shape `[N, 1]`, you can create the network as

```
y = b + tf.matmul(X, W, name='y')
```

Now, you can create your loss around your true `label` and `y`.
You can find more information on [tensorflow tutorials page](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/). Go through the `MNIST` tutorial and that will be more than enough to get started.

Comment: I think the shape of W must be `[4096, N]` instead of 1 and bias is `shape=(N,)`. Am I right? Because I have N class

Comment: N is the size of your dataset (or batch). Weights are for the network. Whether you train on 10, 20, or N inputs, weights remain the same.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention that `N` is number of label

Comment: Even then, both your input and label have N. I do not understand how your input and output sizes are connected?

Comment: Sorry, I will explain as follows: I have a vector1 `4096x1` corresponding to label 1, vector2 `4096x1` corresponding to label 2, vector3 `4096x1` corresponding to label 3, and so on, vectorN`4096x1` corresponding to label N. So the input X may be `4096xN` and label Y is `Nx1`

Comment: So, it seems that `N` is the size of the dataset. If your input is of size `[N, 4096]` and weight of `[4096, 1]`, then using `matmul` will create an output of `[N, 1]` and that is the size of labels

Comment: Yes, you correct. N is size of dataset because the label for each image may be similar.

Comment: So if N is size of dataset, does your weight shape is correct?